# How to get a DocumentContract using Android Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, file-permissions, storage-access-framework

I am trying to implement the SAF in my app. I have managed to copy music files to the external sdcard using the following:

```
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DIRECTORY);
```

which brings up the File/folder Picker

to copy:

```
   private String copyFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, Uri treeUri) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    String error = null;
    DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getActivity(), treeUri);
    String extension = inputFile.substring(inputFile.lastIndexOf(".")+1,inputFile.length());

    try {
        DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("audio/"+extension, inputFile);
        out = getActivity().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());
        in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        error = fnfe1.getMessage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    }
    return error;
}
```

BUT 
when user selected "move" I want to delete the files in the original location(s) which may not be in the documenttree as they have nothing to do with what folder was picked. Their paths are taken from the Mediastore_DATA field. 
Question is how can I get a DocumentContract with those files so that I can delete them?

Comment: Why would you need a DocumentsContract? You just can use the File class to delete them as you have full path which you used for the FileInputStream.

Comment: `which brings up the File/folder Picker`. No. You can only select a folder then. A tree. No file.

Comment: `Their paths are taken from the Mediastore_DATA field.`. Why?. You only showed how you select a destination directory. But you did not tell how the user selected the music files that had to be copied/moved. I think you should tell that too.

Comment: @greenaps, a contract is needed as the delete may take place on the external sdcard. I am only interested in picking the "copy to folder". The music files are entries on a playlist and could thus live on either internal or external memory. The whole idea is to copy or move tracks on a playlist to a new folder and in the case of move, subsequently delete the originals.

Comment: You have not answered my `Why?`. Or gave further info needed to solve your problem.

Comment: to answer your why, you cannot delete on the external sdcard with api19 or above without using the Storage Access Framework

Comment: That is no answer at all of course. Please reread. The question is before that 'Why?'.

Comment: Thank you greenapps but i do not think we are getting somewhere. Thank you for responding

Comment: Dont think! Leads no nothing. Answer! ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to obtain URI permission from SAF w/o invoking another UI.

Since you use MediaStore to obtain media file, you can use ContentResolver.delete() with the Media URI you have to delete it. I assume you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. I don't recommend using File to delete the underlying file directly as MediaStore won't have a chance to clean it up.

Alternatively, you can also try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume.html#createAccessIntent(java.lang.String) to obtain tree URI permission to the entire primary storage. However it only works from API 24.

Comment: ttanxu, thank you have answered my question. I did try to delete using the new File(fullpath_from_Mediastore_DATA).delete(); method but nothing gets deleted on the external sdcard. I was hoping to be able to get the document Tree (a one off intent 
 using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, writing the result in preferences), and then append each track to the documentTree uri.whilst enumerating the tree children. I am using the LocalStorage app from Github as an example

Comment: The link you provided looks promising

Comment: You already obtained `_data` column from MediaStore, you should be able to call `mContext.getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), "lower(_data) = lower(?)", new String[] { path_from_MediaStore_DATA });` to delete the item both from MediaStore and disk if you hold WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION.

Comment: the above will only remove the track entry from Mediastore. It will not delete the actual file. The WRITE_EXTERNAL etc is in the manifest but the whole point is that file.delete will not work so I am back to square 1. I think that is why Google have come up with StorageVolume. Their approach to introducing "security" sees a bit haphazard to me. Thank you for your help. I will check the StorageVolume approach.